# 3D model not showing faces and edges, only vertices

Tags: mesh, vertices, faces, edges

When I downloaded a 3D model with three files, .obj, .mtl, and .bones, I imported the obj file into Blender.  However all I see are vertices, no faces and edges.  I was able to see the 3D mesh in the Preview app though. (I'm on a mac)

[image: dd]

Does the .bones file have anything to do with this?  How can I fix this?

My blender version is 3.3.1

Here's a link to my file:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: What is the model suppposed to look like? Maybe you could share a link to the obj as well? If it's a problem with the obj file then you should probably contact the distributor for troublshooting.

Comment: It's a mystery mountain slide from Super Mario 64  I found this obj in this link: https://www.smwcentral.net/?p=viewthread&t=81858

Comment: @Andy if you have a program that is able to open it, see if it can also save it in another format. Game assets could be optimized beyond (the most) standard implementations of a format, while a 3D program might save it 'correctly'…